# ORMLite android class field is id of other class

Tags: java, android, ormlite

How to implement relationship between 2 classes using ORMLite? I know about foreign field, but i can't add non-string Department field to product class

Class Product

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "PRODUCTS")
public class Product {

    @DatabaseField(id = true)
    private String id;

    @DatabaseField()
    private String name;

    @DatabaseField() //This field is id of Department class
    private String department;
```

Department class

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "DEPARTMENTS")
public class Department {

    @DatabaseField(id = true)
    private String id;

    @DatabaseField()
    private String name;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to implement relationship between 2 classes using ORMLite? I know about foreign field, but i can't add non-string Department field to product class

RTFM please.  Did you look at any of the documentation or examples?  Here's the [docs on foreign objects](http://ormlite.com/docs/foreign).  You can see plainly that you put a `Department` into `Product` not a `String`.  The docs show the `Order` object having an `Account` field.

```
@DatabaseField
private Department department;
```

Behind the scenes, what ORMLite does is actually store just the `id` from the department into your `Product`.  If you actually look at the schema then you will see a string there but you don't do that yourself.

Then when you retrieve your `Product`, it will have a `Department` field but only the `id` will be filled out.

There is also a [foreign object example](https://github.com/j256/ormlite-jdbc/tree/master/src/test/java/com/j256/ormlite/examples/foreign) in the code that may also help.

Comment: Thank you. I've thought that it possible with String fields, but this way is possible for me too. Thank you for ORMLite, it's good.